# Why is my transaction dropped?

Tags: transaction

I am trying to figure out why a user needs to approve a tx multiple times in order for it to finally go through. How could I potentially fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is taken from Based Orion: https://twitter.com/BasedOrion_:

There’s multiple sections of the lifetime of a tx where it can potentially get dropped:

1. At the scheduler: tx compute doesn’t fit into block anymore; other txns have more prio fees; account is write locked too many times
2. At the validator network pipeline: too many txns coming thru, validator only accepts certain amount
3. Rpc: rpc too slow, doesn’t forward fast enough or to the right leader etc

Priority fees help with 1. since it helps prioritize your tx once it actually reaches the runtime scheduler.

Spam-approving helps with 2. Since the more you spam, the likelier it is to be part of the network bunch that the validator accepts.

Having a fast, dedicated rpc helps with 3. since it’s only under load from your requests and not a bajillion others.

Answer (score 0):

If your txes do not get confirmed, and you are sending with `skipPreflight: true`, try disabling it.

Some frens and I have had some success with it:)