# Transaction sended but cannot be found in blockexplorer

Tags: transaction

I just started using Solana and attempted to send a correct transaction asynchronously and simultaneously. To prevent deduplication, I added a nonce to the number of transactions (for example, when sending a transaction, the amount is random).

Strangely, although I successfully sent the transaction via an RPC node and generated a tx id, and I saw this request in the Hellius logs, I cannot find this transaction on the blockchain explorer. For example, this tx id: `2yGmpxxrn28irn4oAxXxsD8AQV1fzQnidK2hhkKfAtcTGXeKJTDrFu1rLAJqKtf6dJxJnYbyAqhnAih9295jqY7m` cannot be found in solscan or other explorers.

Even more peculiar is that if I simply send SOL to an address, out of 20 transactions, there might be 3 that I cannot find immediately on the explorer. However, if I send a complex transaction, like a Raydium swap, up to 15 out of 20 transactions might not be found.  The transactions that can be found on the explorer are all executed normally.

I have already added a nonce to prevent Solana from deduplicating.

How should I continue to investigate this issue? What could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Note that a signature just means your transaction *was signed* (which has nothing to do with wether it was confirmed or even processed on chain), unless otherwise specified by the lib you're using. I'm not sure about how this is with Helius logs, but make sure to double check this with their docs/them.

Once you've made sure of this, you need to differentiate between two kinds of txs that don't show up in the block explorer:

- Doesn't show up right away, but a little later: This can happen because not all RPCs are equally fast, so it might take block explorers a little to index your transaction. Fix here is simple, just check back after a little while.
- Doesn't show up ever, aka transaction failed. This happens on Solana for a variety of reasons that have already been answered below:

Why it happens: [Why is my transaction dropped?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/why-is-my-transaction-dropped)

What you can do about it: [How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/how-can-i-analyze-the-reason-for-frequent-blockheightexceeded-errors/9346#9346)